# Surface in plotly does not cover all data, leaving a gap between surface and highlight

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I am using a plotly surface plot with data that has some missing values.

As you can see in the example below, I am using highlight lines to show the surface does not reach the highlight, leaving a weird empty gap. It is not a matter of perspective, as the gap also shows in a cenital plane.

To be more specific, below I am hovering on `row 12`, `column 2006`, and although the missing data starts in `row 13`, in the plot the missing data seems to start before `row 12` ("`row 11.9`"). My expectation would be that the purple surface would reach all the way to the bright blue highlight in `row 12`.

Is this a bug, or there is a parameter to make sure this does not happen?

Thanks!

```
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
DF_RAW = structure(c(181, 163, 60, 124, 76, 62, 73, 59, 17, 21, 26, 7, NA, NA, NA, 
                     188, 145, 61, 130, 61, 59, 62, 57, 20, 22, 22, 6, NA, NA, NA, 
                     137, 154, 54, 191, 75, 56, 65, 56, 22, 27, 33, 14, NA, NA, NA, 
                     126, 185, 65, 109, 51, 71, 57, 38, 25, 23, 21, 10, NA, NA, NA, 
                     150, 144, 44, 123, 58, 24, 48, 41, 19, 26, 21, 5, NA, NA, NA, 
                     138, 137, 61, 130, 67, 34, 60, 44, 19, 21, 16, 4, NA, NA, NA, 
                     121, 146, 101, 92, 70, 74, 88, 33, 18, 39, 24, 12, NA, NA, NA, 
                     NA, 160, 129, 117, 70, 61, 42, 35, 22, 25, 21, 7, 10, 23, 8, 
                     NA, 129, 130, 107, 64, 61, 44, 25, 23, 30, 18, 11, 20, 58, 40, 
                     NA, 136, 131, 96, 53, 31, 51, 37, 43, 31, 19, 2, 22, 40, 41, 
                     NA, 124, 154, 74, 62, 44, 34, 15, 26, 23, 20, 6, 23, 10, 19, 
                     NA, 126, 251, 76, 73, 84, 47, 40, 32, 25, 32, 6, 13, 10, 13, 
                     NA, 129, 194, 91, 53, 99, 46, 34, 60, 21, 17, 6, 14, 14, 26, 
                     NA, 115, 119, 88, 64, 108, 37, 24, 49, 26, 17, 6, 15, 15, 47), 
                   .Dim = 15:14, 
                   .Dimnames = list(c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15"), 
                                    c("2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019")))

DF = DF_RAW
plot1 = plotly::plot_ly(x = ~ colnames(DF),
                y = ~ rownames(DF),
                z = ~ DF) %>% 
  plotly::add_surface(name = "3D mesh",
                      connectgaps = TRUE, hidesurface = TRUE,
                      contours = list(
                        x = list(show = TRUE, width = 1,  highlightwidth = 2, highlightcolor = "#41a7b3", highlight = TRUE),
                        y = list(show = TRUE, width = 1,  highlightwidth = 2, highlightcolor = "#41a7b3", highlight = TRUE),
                        z = list(show = FALSE, width = 1,  highlightwidth = 2, highlightcolor = "#41a7b3", highlight = FALSE)
                      )) %>% 
  plotly::add_surface(name = "surface",
                      connectgaps = FALSE,
                      contours = list(
                        x = list(show = F, width = 1,  highlightwidth = 2, highlightcolor = "#41a7b3", highlight = TRUE),
                        y = list(show = F, width = 1,  highlightwidth = 2, highlightcolor = "#41a7b3", highlight = TRUE),
                        z = list(show = FALSE, width = 1,  highlightwidth = 2, highlightcolor = "#41a7b3", highlight = FALSE)
                      )
   )

plot1
```

[image]

EDIT:To emphasize that this is not a matter of perspective, here a cenital view of the plot. The gap is still visible.

```
plot1 %>% 
  plotly::layout(
    scene = list(
      camera = list(
        eye = list(x = 0, y = 0, z = 2),
        center = list(x = 0, y = 0, z = 0),
        up = list(x = 0, y = 0, z = 1)
        )
      )
    )
```

[image]

And if we get rid of the 3d mesh and show only the surface with the highlight, see how in row 11 (right) is very clear we have all the data (blue highlight goes all the way from top to bottom) but in row 12 it seems we only have data up to 2013 (blue line stops there).

```
plotly::plot_ly(x = ~ colnames(DF),
                y = ~ rownames(DF),
                z = ~ DF, showscale = FALSE) %>% 
  plotly::add_surface(name = "surface",
                      connectgaps = FALSE,
                      contours = list(
                        x = list(show = F, width = 1,  highlightwidth = 2, highlightcolor = "#41a7b3", highlight = TRUE),
                        y = list(show = F, width = 1,  highlightwidth = 2, highlightcolor = "#41a7b3", highlight = TRUE),
                        z = list(show = FALSE, width = 1,  highlightwidth = 2, highlightcolor = "#41a7b3", highlight = FALSE)
                        )
                      ) %>% 
  plotly::layout(
    scene = list(
      xaxis = list(showspikes = FALSE),
      yaxis = list(showspikes = FALSE),
      zaxis = list(showspikes = FALSE),
      camera = list(
        eye = list(x = 0, y = 0, z = 2),
        center = list(x = 0, y = 0, z = 0),
        up = list(x = 0, y = 0, z = 1)
      )
    )
  )
```

[image]

Comment: If I understand what you're asking, the NA's in your dataset are the values you believe you are missing. What you're hovering on is the edge of row 12. the first have of rows 13, 14, and 15 are NA.

Comment: Yes, NA's are information I don't have. As you say, the first half of rows 13 to 15 is missing, and that area is white, which is fine. But as you can see in the plot, the white area goes a bit beyond the blue highlight line in row 12. I would expect the purple surface to reach the blue line. Right now it seems there is also missing info in row 12...

Comment: I'm 99.99999999% sure that that is perspective. Have you orbited or rotated the graph to look at this from other perspectives?

Comment: Kat, I added cenital views of the plot, so you can see the gap is still there. If you only show the surface and highlight, it is very weird how the highlight stops at the gap.